# Unresolved attribute reference 'objects' for class 'GeneralSettings'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

**Django 3.1.7**

**Python 3.8.5**

```
class Branch(models.Model):
    def get_external_dir(self) -> str:
        """
        Get the path to where all external files
        for this branch must be put.
        """

        general_settings = generals_models.GeneralSettings.objects.get(key="general_settings")


class GeneralSettings(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=16, null=False, default="general_settings")
    ...
```

**Problem**

Pycharm shows me a warning:

```
Unresolved attribute reference 'objects' for class 'GeneralSettings'
```

[image]

I'm struggling for a stylish code. I don't want this warning as it irritates me.

Could you tell me:

1. Why is such a warning appear and how to cope with it?
2. Should I just ignore it like this?
   [image]

Comment: The member `objects` is dynamically added by Django to your model so most IDE's would mark it unless some plugin, etc. is used. Pycharm's professional version has much better (out of the box) support for Django. You can try using [pylint-django](https://pypi.org/project/pylint-django/) with pycharm for community edition.

Comment: And yes you can ask Pycharm to ignore it